# TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined ; install library boron

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I installed the https://github.com/yuanyan/boron library, but I have error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined
>   push../node_modules/boron/modalFactory.js.module.exports
>   C:/Users/m/Desktop/chrome-extension/node_modules/boron/modalFactory.js:10
>   7 | module.exports = function (animation) {    8 |   return
>   React.createClass({    9 |     propTypes: {
>
> > 10 |       className: React.PropTypes.string,   11 |       // Close the modal when esc is pressed? Defaults to true.   12 |
> >     keyboard: React.PropTypes.bool,   13 |       onShow:
> >     React.PropTypes.func,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like boron has a dependency of `prop-types`. Adding it via `npm` should resolve the issue:

```
npm install --save prop-types
```

Comment: Do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. The error is related to prop-types being externalized but `npm install --save prop-types` won't fix it entirely.

I found this forked repo which has updated boron as reboron to React 15+ https://github.com/bold-commerce/reboron which fixes the issue and gets rid of the error for me. You'll have to update your import statements at the very least.